# Repeated NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported tried the previous solutions to no avail

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook

I keep getting the error when i try to connect to the database through jupyter notebooks.
I tried all the solutions such as:
Reinstalling mysql-connector-python (didnt work)
Passing in the arguement `auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'`
Making sure that the mysql is up to date and matches my python version (3.9)
I have tried everything and i still get the error.

This is my code:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = 'root',
    passwd = 'oxxmcN4Fer7@HQie',
    database = 'testdb',
    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
pip uninstall mysql-connector-python
```

and

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

in windows command line window.

If it failed, try to

`reconfigure` MySql server

from `MySql installer`

then choose `Use Legacy Authentication Method (Retain MySql 5x Compatibility)`
in `Authentication Method`

`Reconfiguring MySql server` and `reinstalling mysql connector python` had removed my error

Comment: For me the error indeed was that I had `mysql-connector` instaled instead of `mysql-connector-python`.

Comment: The above answer had worked for me